# How to change page content in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a master page that has a content division. Depending on which menu item is clicked, I would like to change the content accordingly.

Example: If "About us" is clicked then I would include the about us content in the content `div`.

Comment: You need to use Javascript and [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) for that.

Comment: Where is the content you want to fetch stored?

Comment: The content will be stores in another php file

Comment: My advise is to use a framework like laravel (in php) where this is done in a better and more efficient way for you. https://laravel.com/

Comment: @Murillio4 - Really? He should use and learn a big PHP-framework just to update a div using Ajax? That's like using a sledgehammer to nail in a tiny nail. And he still needs to learn Ajax, regardless... we can also talk about the efficiency of loading and bootstrapping a big framework vs. using a few lines of Javascript.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson In my opinion, using a framework when you'r building a website is a good solution. Tho if you are creating it for educational purposes, maybe going all vanilla is the best way.

Comment: @Murillio4 - I would argue that it totally depends on what kind of site your building. Either way, that shouldn't be the first recommendation for someone as soon as they have a question about how to do something. Help them to solve their issue with pure PHP/JS and let them find a framework that fits the bill afterwords.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I agree with you. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks guys i will be checking on how do it with js and ajax later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On PHP without JS. 
You will need to pass a page identifier by POST or GET methods

Click on such a link on a page will send a GET request to masterpage called index.php with variable 'content_id' of 'about' value

```
<a href="index.php?content_id=about">About Us</a>
```

In the PHP script you will need to get by PHP this variable from web server.
like

```
<?php
    $content=$_GET['content_id']; // _GET is web server array with get variables
?>
```

in the content section of your master page there could be an 
'if' or 'case' construction which will include a required content

```
<?php
    if ($content == 'about'){
    echo "About We are the Best";
    // you could include a file or data from database here
}else{
    echo "Some other page";
}
?>
```

p.s. PHP has a lot of already mature frameworks with templates, no need to write one from scratch :-)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, i will check it later on, i think this will work for my purpose